# Powershell handling Format-Hex for UserSID in mssql

Tags: sql-server, powershell

My code is capturing the output from the sql table by running `sp_change_users_login 'report'`

It is returning two things - a) Username and b)usersid

UserSId is coming in binary with commas so I am using `Format-Hex` to get the original SID of the user.
But with this conversion, it is returning other things too. I wish to handle that. Below is the picture with the output.

**PS OUTPUT:**

[image: Output Coming in PS]

**SQL Output**

[image: SQL Output]

How can I handle it and get only the same output as in mssql?

My piece of Code:

```
   if($DBs -is [System.Array])
        {
            foreach($DB in $DBs)
            {
            $DB
            $connection.ChangeDatabase($DB)
            $connection.ChangeDatabase('DBName') ## Currently hardcoded.In actual, it will iterate.
              $orphan_users_query = @"
                sp_change_users_login 'report'

"@
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $orphan_users_query
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $object_orphan= New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $object_orphan.Load($result)
        $object_orphan.UserSID | Format-Hex -Raw #| Out-File C:\temp\outfile_property1.txt -Append -Force
            }
        }
```

Comment: take a look at this ... PowerShell hex to string conversion - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229866/powershell-hex-to-string-conversion

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: It will not help in my case. My matchcase is way too tricky to discard the other things and pick only the hex one.. Also, in an iteration, it would be very hard to deal with. I am working on regex with substring to pick the particular one, but unsure if its gonna work at all.

Comment: Your UserSID attribute already only contains the SID. So why would it not be applicable? `Format-Hex` is not meant to do a conversion it's a visual aid for human readable interpretation.

Comment: What type is `$result` / `$object_orphan.UserSID`? In general get the 1st 16 bytes and format `X2`, prepend with `0x`. Maybe `$OFS = '' ; -join ('0x'+([system.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($object_orphan.UserSID.Substring(0,16)) | %{"{0:X2}" -f $_})) ; $OFS = $Null`

Comment: @RanadipDutta - that doesn't make sense to me ... but you are the one who has the task to do, so do it as you need. [*grin*]

Comment: @LotPings: Its a match and type is System.Object. Out of which I am picking the first index and converting that to string so that I can use substring and regex to pick the right one. More or less the approach what you have given is what I intend to do. I will post an answer once I will figure out. But Yes, you expression helped me on the join part which I never considered.

Comment: @Seth: Try running the same and you will understand that PS does convert things to binary with comma separator. I have already given screenshots where after conversion only I am getting the appropriate Hex code with other obfuscation. `Format-Hex` is exactly meant for conversion like this kind of scenario but there are variations like what LotPings have shared is the closest one.

Comment: What other obfuscation are you talking about? The output of `Format-Hex` is correct. Each line is the same as the SQL output. As you are not iterating the UserSIDs you are getting an array of three objects and those are converted to hex. As you are using a cmdlet which is meant for human debugging you will need to manually convert those values to hex if you want to use them somewhere else. Something like `Foreach ($element in $string.toCharArray()){$hexString += " " + [System.String]::Format("{0:X}", [System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element))}`

Comment: Did you get the right side part? That is obfuscation. And also the output is not a string. It is a single object. So conversion of that will give path and hex table columns too, which we need to eliminate. Each single SID is resulting  a single object. Run the query in mssql. If you have any orphan user , try the above code, you will get to know what I meant... Its not string. what I am doing is another level of iteration and `(($object_orphan.UserSID | Format-Hex -Raw | Select-String '000000')[0]).ToString().Substring(0,59)`

Comment: I think here may be what you were looking for: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349768/how-to-retrieve-the-sql-server-sid-in-string-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled the obfuscation coming as an output with a decent formatting.

```
foreach($DB in $DBs)
{

$Orphan_query = @"
        select p.name,p.sid
        from $DB.sys.database_principals p
        where p.type in ('G','S','U')
        and p.sid not in (select sid from sys.server_principals)
        and p.name not in (
            'dbo',
            'guest',
            'INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
            'sys',
            'MS_DataCollectorInternalUser'
        ) ;
"@
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $Orphan_query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$object= New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$object.Load($result)

        If($object)
        {

        "Database Name : $DB" 
        "USER :: SID" 
            [System.Array]$Actual_sid = ($object.sid | Format-Hex -ErrorAction Ignore | Select-String '00000') 
            [System.Array]$names = $object.name

            If($Actual_sid.Length -match $names.Length) 
            {
                For($i=0;$i -lt $Actual_sid.Length; $i++) 
                {
                    "$($names[$i]) :: $("0x"+$Actual_sid[$i].ToString().Substring(11,47).replace(' ','') )"  
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Output is now like this

```
Database Name : soxmon

USER :: SID

test :: 0x9F8857FB265BB64BA962D468C3D0A450
L1test :: 0xD95D5C3B201FE846B4C61A175F4ACC32
L1Login :: 0x0488468E6AEE14428B6BF7528CA01EA3
```

which is exactly matching as per the sql output. So, the automatic binary conversion was causing the issue in actual.